# Use JsonProperty if it exists otherwise use camelcase

Tags: c#, json, json-serialization

I have the following class:

```
public sealed class CRMUser
{
    /// The display name.
    /// </value>
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("email")]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("phone")]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Which when I returned it as Json in a controller eg

```
return Json(crmUser);
```

it was returning the object with camel case and ignoring the `JsonProperty` attributes.  To get around this, I had to add the following:

```
services.AddControllers()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        // this allows us to use the JsonProperty attribute when returning Json in an action
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver(); // this resolver is from newtonsoft.json
    });
```

This works but now any class that I haven't used `JsonProperty` attribute on is no longer camel case - is there a way to get it to use the property if it exists and if not, fall back to camel casing?

Comment: Did you try passing in [`CamelCaseNamingStrategy`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NamingStrategyCamelCase.htm) to the contract resolver?

Comment: Perfect, that's done the trick - if you add that as an answer I can accept it.  Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To tell Json.Net to use camel casing by default, you have to provide that option when creating the `DefaultContractResolver`:

```
DefaultContractResolver contractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
{
    NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy()
};
```

The [docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NamingStrategyCamelCase.htm) go into more details.